# Scrapy to print results in real time rather than waiting for crawl to finish

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible for scrapy to print the results in real-time? I'm planning to crawl large sites and fear that if my vpn connection cuts off, crawl effort will just be wasted since it won't print any results.

I'm currently using VPN with rotating user agents and I know it's ideal to use rotating proxies instead of VPN but that will be for the future script upgrade.

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

results = open('results.csv','w')

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    with open("domains.txt", "r") as d:
        allowed_domains = [url.strip() for url in d.readlines()]

    with open("urls.txt", "r") as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        f.close()

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/'), deny=('9','10')), follow=True, callback='parse_item'),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for pattern in ['Albert Einstein', 'Bob Marley']:
            result = re.findall(pattern, response.text) 
            print(response.url,">",pattern,'>',len(result), file = results)
```

Many thanks in advance.

**Updates**

The script from harada works perfectly without any changes at all apart from the save file. All I needed to do was to make some modifications to the current files as below in order for everything to work.

spider - defined items

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from ..items import TestItem

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    with open("domains.txt", "r") as d:
        allowed_domains = [url.strip() for url in d.readlines()]

    with open("urls.txt", "r") as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        f.close()

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/'), deny=('9','10')), follow=True, callback='parse_item'),)

    def parse_item(self, response):

        items = TestItem()

        for pattern in ['Albert Einstein', 'Bob Marley']:
            result = re.findall(pattern, response.text) 
            url = response.url
            count = len(result)

            items['url'] = url
            items['pattern'] = pattern
            items['count'] = count

            yield(items)
```

items.py - added items as fields

```
import scrapy

    class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
        url = scrapy.Field()
        pattern = scrapy.Field()
        count = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py - uncommented ITEM_PIPELINES

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'test.pipelines.TestPipeline': 300,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a script to your pipeline that can save the data you have at that time to a file. Add a counter to the pipeline as a variable, and when the pipeline reaches a certain threshold (let's say, each 1000 items yielded), it should write to a file. The code would look something like this. I tried to make it as general as possible.

```
class MyPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        # variable that keeps track of the total number of items yielded
        self.total_count = 0
        self.data = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.data.append(item)
        self.total_count += 1
        if self.total_count % 1000 == 0:
            # write to your file of choice....
            # I'm not sure how your data is stored throughout the crawling process
            # If it's a variable of the pipeline like self.data,
            # then just write that to the file
            with open("test.txt", "w") as myfile:
                myfile.write(f'{self.data}')

        return item
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just started Scrapy/Python a week ago so I'm just trying to figure how and what to add on processes.

Comment: @AJ2 No problem, I edited my answer for a bit more clarity of my example. In theory, you can (and are highly encouraged to) use feed exports instead. Look here for more info: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/stable/topics/feed-exports.html

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! I just needed to make some adjustments to the current files and it works flawlessly.